# When is an After Effects question a GD:SE or VP:SE question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Just wondering (as I'm starting to learn AE)...

Is there a clear definition for when an After Effect question is appropriate for Graphic Design and when should it be posted to Video Production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think we have really set one. We're not supposed to be a software support website though it feels that way more often than it should.

My own take is if it has to do with AE for Graphics and Motion Animation then its acceptable to ask here probably.

If it is more related to integration, audio, export settings, and stuff of that nature then it might be better to ask on [video.stackexchange.com](http://video.stackexchange.com) or [sound.stackexchange.com](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) or if more of a "My AE stopped working as intended" then perhaps even [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) is the better place.

When in doubt I'd say just ask the question and if the community doesn't like it, they can vote to close/migrate.